# cakephp2系でfilebinderのプラグインを使いたいのですが

Tags: cakephp

お世話になっております。

filebinderをgithubからダウンロードして手順どうりファイルを作成しましたが、

```
Missing Component 
Error: TransitionComponent could not be found. 

Error: Create the class TransitionComponent below in file: app/Controller/Component/TransitionComponent.php
```

とでています。 
app/Plugin/Filebinder/Controller/Component 
にはTransitionComponent.phpは確かに入っておらず、自分で作成、または、他サイトからダウンロードしなくてはならないのですか？ 
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fusic/filebinder https://github.com/fusic/filebinder/

こちらのREADMEにあるサンプルでは、TransitionComponentが必要とされていますね。

TransitionComponentは以下から入手できます。

https://github.com/hiromi2424/TransitionComponent

FileBinderのサンプルではコンポーネント名の記述が`'Transition'`のみとなっていますが、TransitionComponentをプラグインとして導入する場合、プラグイン名も含めた記述`'Transition.Transition'`に変更してください。